# Custom migration tools from Lotus notes to SharePoint

Tags: migration, lotus-notes

I need to know steps involved to migrate lotus notes data to SharePoint through a custom migrator tools.

I know only few steps:

1. use c++ or VC++ (?possible) to connect to lotus notes tools through OLE provider.
2. develop COM component which bridges gap to develop SharePoint application through visual studio c#

is there any more or other steps required?

please reply with proper steps explaining how COM helps in integrating in between?

Comment: Could you clarifty your question a little bit? You mention migration tools and then integration. Do you want to migrate from Lotus Notes to SharePoint or looking to integrate your SharePoint environment with existing Lotus Notes infrastructure?

Comment: Here I want to get schema and data of lotus notes forms and views etc in to SharePoint and do programming in c#. Lotus notes can be accessed through OLE provider that also through c++ or vc++. We need a COM component to work in between of c++ and it's out put to be accessed through c#. Then only we can get LN data in to SharePoint. Exactly here COM is coming in to picture.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, might be worth looking at the following CodeProject page as it shows interaction between Lotus Notes and C# application: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18517/Lotus-Notes-Integration-with-Microsoft-NET-Platfor

When I get back from work I will be able to check if there's off the shelf interop library solution you could use.